# Нейросеть не распознает цифры

Tags: python, keras

Написал по урокам нейросеть для распознавания рукописных цифр.
Обучается без ошибок, цифры из базы данных mnist распознает безошибочно, но когда пытаюсь загрузить свой пример цифры (нарисовал в photoshop), она все время ошибается.
После всех преобразований (уменьшение картинки до 28x28 пикселей, перевод в градации серого и тд), вывожу изображение цифры, вроде бы визуально понятно, что это за число, но она не понимает.
Вопрос №2 В конце кода закоменчено 2 строки img = img.reshape(1,28,28) # img = img/255.0
Вместо этого я прописал **reshape в model.predict(img.reshape(28,28,1))**, потому что иначе выскакивает ошибка
**Input 0 of layer "dense" is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 784, but received input with shape (None, 28)**
Я понимаю, что это связано с размером, но не понимаю, что нужно исправлять, хотя если прописать уже в **model.predict**, то код хотя бы срабатывает

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from PIL import Image
import PIL.ImageOps
%matplotlib

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train / 255
x_test = x_test / 255
y_train_cat = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train,10)
y_test_cat = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test,10)

model = keras.Sequential([
                          Flatten(input_shape=(28,28,1)),
                          Dense(128,activation='relu'),
                          Dense(10, activation='softmax')
   ])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.evaluate(x_test,y_test_cat)
model.save('test_model.h5')

img = Image.open('Devat.png')
img = img.resize((28, 28))
img = PIL.ImageOps.invert(img)
img = img.convert('1')
img = np.array(img)
# img = img.reshape(1,28,28)
# img = img/255.0
plt.imshow(img, cmap=plt.cm.binary) 
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()

res = model.predict(img.reshape(28,28,1))[0]
print(np.argmax(res), max(res))
```

Comment: А вы покажите всё-таки вашу картинку и напишите, как именно ошибается нейросеть. Может быть это окажется вполне объяснимо.

Comment: @CrazyElf вот ссылка на скриншот https://wampi.ru/image/RjS5rwk , она уверена, что это цифра 5, причем на 100%, выше вывел, как делается вывод самой картинки после обработок
и так с любым числом, которое я загружаю